# Google Scripts CSV file returning boxes and question marks

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, encoding

I am able to fetch the CSV I want from the Google API; however - I think the encoding is not quite right as I'm getting boxes and question marks.

Anyone know what could be the cause and how I can encode it properly?

[image]

```
function getPlayData(){
  var main = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('main');
  var token = tokenRefresh();
  var now = new Date();
  var oneMonthAgo = new Date();
  oneMonthAgo.setMonth(oneMonthAgo.getMonth() - 1);
  var oneMonthAgo = Utilities.formatDate(oneMonthAgo, "GMT+1", "yyyyMM"); 

  var currentMonth = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "yyyyMM"); 
  for(i=0; i<1; i++){
    var options = {
      'headers':
      {
        'Authorization' : 'Bearer '+token
      }
    }
    var url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/XXXXXXX/stats/installs/installs_overview.csv";
    var csv_response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
    var response = Utilities.parseCsv(csv_response, ',');
    for(j=0; j<response.length; j++)
    {
      main.getRange(3+j, 2, 1, 1).setValue(response[j][0])
    }
  }

  var a = '';

}
```

Just found out in its raw form - Google somehow stores the CSV in this format!
[image: RAW]

Comment: I think that to provide a sample data and script which can replicate your situation will help users think of yoyur solution.

Comment: @Tanaike: Done.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Comment: I'm not sure about the CSV values, for example, when you modify to ``var csv_response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options).getContentText("UTF-8")``, what result will you retrieve?

Comment: `var csv_response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options).getContentText("UTF-8");`
    


`var response = Utilities.parseCsv(csv_response, ',');`


Will fetch the same...

Comment: I'm sorry for the inconvenience. Can you provide the CSV values or sample CSV data which can replicate your situation?

Comment: Just found our in ATOM EDITOR that the CSV RAW format that Google produces is in this format! https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjJEW.png and using ATOM it appears that it's UTF-16 LE encoding so I'll try to force that.

Comment: I'm glad your issue was solved. I'm sorry for my poor skill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the encoding was in UTF-16 rather than UTF-8. Once it's forced to UTF-16 using:

```
var csv_response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options).getContentText("UTF-16");
```

It works like a treat.